# can i delete the mrt.exe files

Tags: windows-8, malware

I found these files in my F: drive inside folders having really long names like **'5d458b2b9d3d1d12a6e4176ebea6'**. I tried to find something about it and got really confused.

Some sites say it is created by Windows Malware Removal tool while on one site I found that it was a malware.

If it is Windows generated then why do I have multiple copies of this files under similar strange folders.

I just want to know if it is **safe to delete those multiple copies** keepnig just the recent one to free some memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming F: is not the partition that Windows is installed on. The Malicious Software Removal Tool might have run multiple times and created new folders/files on each run, although ordinarily it should have cleaned up after itself. If you've scanned your system (say with something like [this](https://www.malwarebytes.org)) and are sure it's not infected, I'd say you can get rid of all those folders. If you want to be sure it's safe just move them all elsewhere, then reboot and wait and see if something complains. If not you can get rid of them.